# Ошибка юникода в "ConfigParser"

Tags: python-3.x, config, configuration

Есть конфиг со следующим содержанием:

```
[config]
fontname = Times
fontsize = 12
ffpmeg_path = ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe

mp3-wav = -acodec pcm_u8 -ar 22050
wav-mp3 = -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192 -f mp3

fextensions = mp1,mp2,mp3,mp4,ogg,avi,flac

[ru_RU]
mainwin = ffmpeg GUI
filemenu = Файл
openfile = Открыть
appquit = Выход
choosefile = Выберите файл
filepath_cells = Файл
filesize_cells = Размер
fileffi_cells = Формат
fileffo_cells = Результат
accept = Ок
cancel = Отмена

[en_EN]
mainwin = ffmpeg GUI
formatswin = File format
filemenu = File
openfile = Open
appquit = Quit
choosefile = Choose file
filepath_cells = File
filesize_cells = Size
fileffi_cells = Input
fileffo_cells = Output
accept = Ok
cancel = Cancel
```

И функция для обработки этого конфига:

```
    def get_info(self,section,key,rv=0,rt=str,sep=None):
        cf = configparser.ConfigParser(
            allow_no_value=True,
                interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation()
        )
        cf.readfp(codecs.open('config.ini','r','utf8'))

        if sep == None:
            return ''.join(rt(cf[section][key]))
        else:
            return ''.join(cf[section][key].split(sep))
```

При попытке вызова `print(main.get_info(0,'config','fontname'))` выскакивает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 132, in <module>
  print(main.get_info(0,'config','fontname'))
File "main.py", line 124, in get_info
  cf.readfp(codecs.open('config.ini','r','utf8'))
File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 735, in readfp
  self.read_file(fp, source=filename)
File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 690, in read_file
self._read(f, source)
File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 1057, in _read
raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.  
file: 'config.ini', line: 1
'\ufeff[config]\r\n'
```

В начале файла имеется "#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
". Пробовал редактировать конфиг через обычный блокнот - всё работает. Как только я открываю его через "Sublime Text 3" все русские символы "ломаются". Что я делаю не так?

Comment: обычный блокнот уже умеет utf-8?

Comment: # -*- coding: cp1251 -*-